# SwiftUI combine search text

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I have backend API /search?q=New Je which is return list of JSON cities

- "city": "New Jersey"
- "city": "New Jenny Lind"
- "city": "New Jerusalem"
- ...

I have a class

```
final class LocationStore: ObservableObject{
     @Published var List : [LocationModel] = []
     func search(q: String) {
         call backend search API and assign to List
     }

}
```

and I have search TextField in my view.

How to call search api and assign to my list when user type in search TextField. Need to show dropdown after type 3 character in TextField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loose structure of how you tackle something like this:

- Set up a text field that you can observe the output from in some fashion.
- If you want to use Combine, create a pipeline that sends the value of that field on every change, and then trigger some output when it matches your spec (>3 characters)
- when the combine pipeline triggers, use the value provided, or just the nature of the trigger, to do whatever action you have in mind.

There's sample code that does nearly exactly this available online within [Using Combine](https://gum.co/usingcombine) in the pattern named [Declarative UI updates from user input](https://heckj.github.io/swiftui-notes/#patterns-update-interface-userinput). It covers a bit more. The [github project that hosts](https://github.com/heckj/swiftui-notes) Using Combine has a SwiftUI variation of this as well in the project if you'd prefer to see it with SwiftUI.